# Why does this one line take SO long?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put a lot of identical formulas in to a medium sized range. And it is taking forever to process. The code I am using is:

```
.Range("M2:AZ1000").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(MOODLE!C[-5],""Y"",MOODLE!C3,RC3)"
```

but the line takes about five minutes to run.

I have tried switching calculation off, inserting the formulas then back on (this INCREASES the time it takes as it seems to now calculate twice!).

Comment: Do you have any volatile functions in the workbook? Particularly in columns H:AU (e.g. INDIRECT, OFFSET, NOW, TODAY, etc). fwiw, you are writing 39,960 formulas; mine takes ~80 seconds; what is the extent (last row) of MOODLE?

Comment: Addendum: Is there a Worksheet_Change for that worksheet or a Workbook_Sheetchange for the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons for your problem:

1. your formula itself requires lots of calculation. A column has `2^10` rows. In your formula, you input two whole column into the `criteria_range` fields, it means Excel has `2^10 + 2^10` of `IF` to check, and that only is for one cell. You apply it to `39960` cells. Try limit the input of `criteria_range` to a smaller range. (In my experience, when using `COUNTIF` with `criteria_range` of 10,000 cells and applying the formula over 10,000 cells, things start to get very sloppy).
2. you have other Excel open which also has many volatile functions. Try closing them.

Also, may be turning calculation to Manual mode would ease the pain?